# Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, pdo

I see a lot of people having this issue but all the answers always point to the count not matching the value count but they both have 9 items so not sure why its giving me such an error? Guess i've missed the obvious?

```
    $sth = "INSERT INTO `docs` (title, ref, rev, content, owner, contract_id, cat_id, created, updated)
                VALUES (:title, :ref, :rev, :content, :owner, :contract :cat, NOW(), NOW())";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sth);
    $q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':ref'=>$ref, ':rev'=>$rev, ':content'=>$contnet, ':owner'=>$owner, ':contract'=>$contract, ':cat'=>$cat));
```

Comment: as in the title 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' in /var/www/html/infosite/contracts/universal/docs/submitdoc.php:27 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/infosite/contracts/universal/docs/submitdoc.php(27): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/infosite/contracts/universal/docs/submitdoc.php on line 27

Comment: Is this a typo? `':content'=>$contnet` should it be `$content` ?

Comment: @NeigylR.Noval its in the title `1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Comment: @Dale yes thats a typo thanks for spotting, this isn't causing the above error though.

Comment: also when we use seeder and forget to remove unwanted fields from one of the records in array of seeder. all arrays should be the same when we use seeder in laravel

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're missing a comma here: (in the VALUES())

```
:contract :cat
```

This

```
$sth = "INSERT INTO `docs` (title, ref, rev, content, owner, contract_id, cat_id, created, updated) VALUES (:title, :ref, :rev, :content, :owner, :contract :cat, NOW(), NOW())";
```

Should be

```
 $sth = "INSERT INTO `docs` (title, ref, rev, content, owner, contract_id, cat_id, created, updated) VALUES (:title, :ref, :rev, :content, :owner, :contract, :cat, NOW(), NOW())";
```

Comment: thanks Dale can't believe i missed that, its been a long day. I will accept once the time limit on accepting an answer has ran out, thanks for your help

Comment: Tip for the next time use the query and replace the value and try it again, and then replace them back 1 at the time.

Comment: Dont know why this question "closed as too localized" but it helped me just now 5 years later... thanks bro